# Assigning the attribute for separate picture srcset and img src

Tags: jquery

My code below is working when there is only 1 picture tag on the website. Picture tag is automatically created dynamically when they add images in the backend. So I am assigning the data attribute's value to the img src and other to source srcset

When there are multiple images, all the picture tags are having the first image source itself. I want srcset or src of its same element not of other picture element's.
I'm banging my head, thanks for your inputs in advance.

```js
var is_chrome = (typeof window.chrome === 'object' && navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Edge') === -1);

if ($('.image-browsers').length > 0) {
  if (is_chrome) {
    var mobWebp = $('.mobileImages').attr('data-mobileWebp'),
      deskWebp = $('.desktop-images').attr('data-desktopWebp');
    $('.mobileImages').attr('srcset', mobWebp);
    $('.desktop-images').attr('src', deskWebp);
  } else {
    var mobImage = $('.mobileImages').attr('data-mobileImage'),
      deskImage = $('.desktop-images').attr('data-desktopImage');
    $('.mobileImages').attr('srcset', mobImage);
    $('.desktop-images').attr('src', deskImage);
  }
}
```

```html
<picture class="image-browsers">
  <isif condition="${mobileImage}">
    <source class="mobileImages" srcset="" media="(max-width: 768px)" data-mobileImage="${mobileImage ? mobileImage.getURL() : ''}" data-mobileWebp="${mobilewebpImage ? mobilewebpImage.getURL() : ''}">
  </isif>
  <isif condition="${desktopImage}">
    <img class="desktop-images" src="" alt="${'previewName' in contentAsset.custom && contentAsset.custom.previewName != null ? contentAsset.custom.previewName : '' }" title="${'previewName' in contentAsset.custom && contentAsset.custom.previewName != null ? contentAsset.custom.previewName : '' }"
      data-desktopImage="${desktopImage ? desktopImage.getURL() : ''}" data-desktopWebp="${desktopwebpImage ? desktopwebpImage.getURL() : ''}">
  </isif>
</picture>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run your code for each `.image-browsers` element

```js
var is_chrome = (typeof window.chrome === 'object' && navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Edge') === -1);
var imageBrowsers = $('.image-browsers');

if (imageBrowsers.length > 0) {
  imageBrowsers.each(function(index, picture) {
    var mobileImage,
      desktopImage;

    if (is_chrome) {
      mobileImage = $('.mobileImages', picture).attr('data-mobileWebp');
      desktopImage = $('.desktop-images', picture).attr('data-desktopWebp')
    } else {
      mobileImage = $('.mobileImages', picture).attr('data-mobileImage');
      desktopImage = $('.desktop-images', picture).attr('data-desktopImage')
    }

    $('.mobileImages', picture).attr('srcset', mobileImage);
    $('.desktop-images', picture).attr('src', desktopImage);
  });
}
```

Comment: Not working. Not sure why.
Please check this site http://dev07-na01-arden.demandware.net/s/ardene/ca/en/homepage/
File name if you try to debug: hero-carousel.js

Comment: @NaveenLBhandari indeed. Sorry abouth that, forgot that the `.each` in jquery takes the index as the first param. Just change `imageBrowsers.each(function( picture) {` to `imageBrowsers.each(function(index, picture) {`. Updated answer as well.

Comment: You are the best. Thanks.